# !=-operator fails for struct

Tags: c#, json.net, xml-serialization

I have some classes that have some serialization-attributes for `XmlSerializer`, e.g. `XmlElement` or `XmlArray`. Now I want to use those existing attributes for Json-serialization also.

Therefor I created a class deriving from NewtonSoft´s `DefaultContractResolver`:

```
public class XmlToJsonContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    internal void ConfigureProperty(MemberInfo member, JsonProperty property)
    {
        ConfigureNamedMembers(member, property);
    }

    private static void ConfigureNamedMembers(MemberInfo member, JsonProperty property)
    {
        foreach (var attribute in member.GetCustomAttributesData().Where(x => x.AttributeType.Namespace == typeof(XmlElementAttribute).Namespace))
        { 
            // the elementName may either be stored in the named argument "ElementName" or was provided to the 
            // constructor of the appropriate Xml-attribute
            var item = attribute.NamedArguments?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MemberName == "ElementName");
            if (item.HasValue && item.Value != default(CustomAttributeNamedArgument))
            {
                property.PropertyName = item.Value.MemberName;
                return;
            }

            // ElementName is provided to constructor of xml-attribute
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Now I have a test-class to test the `ConfigureProperty`-method from above:

```
private class A
{
    [XmlElement("AnIntAlias")]
    public int AnXmlSerializableInt { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see the `XmlElementAttribute` has no named arguments. Instead the `ElementName`-proerty is set via its constructor, which is why the code above first checks if there are any named arguments.

This is code that uses `A`:

```
var target = new XmlToJsonContractResolver();
var jsonProperty = new JsonProperty { PropertyName = memberName };
var member = typeof(A).GetMember(nameof(A.AnXmlSerializableInt)).First();
target.ConfigureProperty(member, jsonProperty);

var result = jsonProperty.PropertyName;
```

When I debug this code I the first condition `if (item.HasValue && item.Value != default(CustomAttributeNamedArgument))` is met, which is why I get a `NullReferenceException` at `property.PropertyName = item.Value.MemberName;`.

When I add a watch on `attribute.NamedArguments` (which is a `List<CustomAttributeNamedArgument>` and thus a list of value-types) there are zero elements within that list, so `FirstOrDefault` should return whatever is the default-value for that struct. However the `!=`-operator returns `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `CustomAttributeNamedArgument` struct overrides its equality operators like this:

```
public static bool operator ==(CustomAttributeNamedArgument left, CustomAttributeNamedArgument right)
{
     return left.Equals((object) right);
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return obj == (ValueType)this;
}
```

So basically uses reference equality semantics even though it's a struct. Why exactly it does that is not clear to me, but that's the reason of your check failure. Even this:

```
default(CustomAttributeNamedArgument) == default(CustomAttributeNamedArgument);
```

Returns false with such semantics.

To fix you can use something like

```
var item = attribute.NamedArguments?.Where(x => x.MemberName == "ElementName")
    .Cast<CustomAttributeNamedArgument?>().FirstOrDefault();                
if (item.HasValue) {
    property.PropertyName = item.Value.MemberName;
    return;
}
```

or similar way to return null as default value.

Comment: I see, that makes sense, even though it seems weird.